# Angular $http.get not return data

Tags: angularjs

I created a helper service to wrap the $http.get.

```js
self.apiGet = function (url, success, failure, always) {
           
            $http.get(url)
                .then(function (result) {
                    success(result);
                    if (always != null)
                        always();
                }, function (result) {
                    if (failure != null) {
                        failure(result);
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                    if (always != null)
                        always();
                });
        }
```

In my controller class, the data is not returned to the view when calling getData(val). the data is returned from the api when I debug it.

```js
 $scope.getData = function (val) {
        return helper.apiGet(url,
            function (result) {
                return result.data;
            });
    };
```

Comment: Is your angular app and the api on the same domain?

Comment: they are not in the same domain. I don't think it is csrf related as I can see the data. I just can't figure out why it is returned to the view.

Comment: You mean you have `cors` enabled in the other app (the api)? `csrf` and `cors` are different but I guess you know that already.

Comment: You need to show your view code so we understand your intentions. But I suspect that you are over thinking this ...

Comment: Well, your apiGet() function doesn't return anything. You're reinventing promises poorly. Your apiGet() function doesn't do anything that promises don't allow to do natively, and in a standard way. Read this article, to understand the traps of promises that you fell into: http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/

Comment: JB, I think you have hit the point. I'm very new to angular. The link is very helpful. If I would like to fix apiGet to return data?  How can I do it? I tried to use return success() in the apiGet but it still not working.

Comment: Just return promise instead of callbacks.

Answer (score 4):

You should just use promises properly. So the service becomes:

```
self.apiGet = function(url) {
    return $http.get(url).then(function(result) {
        return result.data;
    });
};
```

... and it's consumed in controller like this:

```
helper.apiGet(url).then(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});
```

Comment: I use Typeahead in my view which requires calling function in my controller, I can't just use the $scope here.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The point is that you just return promise from the service. Then you use it whatever way you need. In your case you can call function instead of `$scope.data = data;`.